# pass javascript object array to a kotlin function

Tags: kotlin

How would one pass a javascript object array to a Kotlin fuction? My problem is, I think, the data type of the data parameter in the kotlin function. The error I get is:

```
     Got unknown argument class: Object[]

     var data = [{"name":"Elim","startDate":"2019-09-09"}....]
     NativeModules.EmployeeProcessor.processData(data,err=>{}, success =>{});
```

the kotlin function is:

```
        processData(data: Array<kotlin.Any>, cb: Callback) {
        for(k in data){
           Log.i(null, k['name'])
           }

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I see you want to convert jsonString to object?

so pls try this:

```
fun <reified T> fromJsonArray(json: String): List<T> {
        val jsonArray = JSONArray(json)
        val result = ArrayList<T>()
        for (index in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
            result.add(fromJson(jsonArray.getString(index)))
        }
        return result
    }
```

how to use:

```
fromJsonArray(jsonString)
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Note the question is about a JavaScript array – not about a JSON object or its string representation.